# Pivot Charts - how to choose columns to show on the graph

Tags: excel, pivot, pivot-table

so far when I want to choose columns which I want to show in the graph, I have to click on the pivot table and then choose columns fom pivot fields. Is there a faster way to do that? I would like to add some nice looking list under the graph from which I could choose columns to show.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the PivotTable, you can add columns directly to the PivotChart using the same interface as for PivotTables. Right click on the PivotChart and select "Show Field List" as the bottom. The control pane will appear on the right.

Building a custom user interface below the PivotChart would require a significant amount of VBA and would not perform as well.